# c# selenium cannot detect element

Tags: c#, selenium, element

I want to logout from reddit using selenium in c#. And I have a little problem and I hope somebody can help me. This is my following code in c#:

```
               var profile = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("span[@class='DFKWwVItcycZV1bKUOyay']"));
//^is for oppening this dropdown menue | https://i.imgur.com/d8r4C6D.png
                profile.Click();
               var logout = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("div[@class='vzhy90YD0qH7ZDJi7xMGw']"));
//to press on logout | https://i.imgur.com/ON2A92f.png
                logout.Click();
```

how the website source look like:

```
<span class="DFKWwVItcycZV1bKUOyay">
[...]
<div class="vzhy90YD0qH7ZDJi7xMGw">Log Out</div>
```

It would better for checking the reddit source itself.

Thank you for reading this

Comment: Those class names, to me, seem like a terrible idea to search for. They look randomly generated.

Comment: When you say it's not working... what does that mean? Does it throw an error? If so, edit your question and post the error message. I'm assuming it's element not found exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPaths are not valid. They should start with `//`, e.g.

```
//div[@class='vzhy90YD0qH7ZDJi7xMGw']
```

The second issue is that the class you are referencing is likely randomly generated and will change often. I would use the "Log Out" text to find the right element.

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("email-collection-tooltip-id")).Click(); // opens the menu
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a/div[text()='Log Out']")).Click(); // logs out
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try clicking the element above this which is a link.

```
<a data-redditstyle="true" class="randomstring" href="/"><svg></svg><div class="vzhy90YD0qH7ZDJi7xMGw">Log Out</div></a>
```

As mjwills mentioned, that class is certain to change one day and will likely break the code. Take another approach by possibly looking for the text "Log Out" then working backwards to the element you want.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question and would be better as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Sometime few elements are not set as displayed true in DOM, in that case we need to click that element forcefully. Actions class is an ability provided by Selenium for handling keyboard and mouse events.

```
var logout = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("DemoAutomationID")); 
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(logout).Click().Perform(); 
//or 
action.MoveToElement(logout).Click().Build().Perform();
```

Comment: What you have is not a valid XPath and you have used exactly the same locator which OP has said does not work.

Comment: please do not post only code , Add a description for more help

Comment: Thanks for the Comment. Just started contributing in Stack Overflow. These will help to improve my contribution.